# Getting error while trying to print totals and sub-totals using AOP in Oracle AOP

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am trying to print the totals and subtotals in my AOP report.

I am using the formula

```
"{array|(min|max|sum|avg):"attributeToApplyTo":takeNullValueIntoAccount:valueForNull}"
```

i the template this translates to:

```
{week|sum:"mon":true:0}
```

using below formula in my template and it has below structure

[image: using below formula in my template and it has below structure]

but when i run it from the APEX page. i get the error:

[image: error message is shown when trying to print the report]

what am i missing?

Comment: AOP is a third-party product. I suggest contacting AOP support.